# Runtime error when using startActivity()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I am trying to use the following method to switch to a different application:

```
private void switchAcitivty() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, TeleJokeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.telejoke.mo/com.telejoke.mo.TeleJokeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.telejoke.mo.TeleJokeActivity.<init>(TeleJokeActivity.java:11)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-10 03:05:51.901: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  ... 11 more
```

Not sure why I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Paste complete stack trace please. Null pointer exception from applications normally points back to some line of code.

Comment: need more `NullPointerException` error logcat message

Comment: done. full stack trace uploaded.

Comment: There is something null in the view of your TellJokeActivity.class

Comment: What is on TeleJokeActivity.java line number 11 ? If there are method calls on an object at that line, debug and print one linebefore that to see if anything coming out to be null

Comment: Usually the nullpointer will lead you to the line of code.

Comment: `Button uploadPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUploadPage);`. That doesn't make sense. I have a button that has that ID in the layout that TeleJokeActivity launches.

Comment: @moesef are you using `setContentView` method to the lay xml?

Comment: WOW. I didn't put that line inside of my onCreate method.... Thanks for the help guys. Dunce move :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some NullPointerException in your Activity Class TeleJokeActivity. make sure you have invoked setContentView before calling findViewById method.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot switch to a different application's activity within the application.
You can switch in between the same applications activities which are specified in the AndroidManifest file. 
 if u are switching  between the same applications activities check whether you have declared in the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch from current activity to an activity in another application tha specify the complete package name of another application in the intent.

eg:Intent i=new Intent(currentclassname.this,com.example.sample.class);

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from one activity to another activity of another application.I have tried this and it worked.